# How can I override a service provided in imported module

Tags: angular

My app module `appModule` is importing a `Module-A` which also importing `Module-AA`

a `service-AA` is provided in `Module-AA` like this: `Providers:[service-AA]`

Under this situation is it possible to override the `service-AA` so the `Module-AA` will use my service instead??

--
Angular 12

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

1. If you want to **globally override** service instance which is registered to some inner modules like `Module-AA` in your case then at the parent module of it (for example app.module.ts is super parent module) you can override service instance by using :
   providers: [ { provide: TokenName, useClass: NewTokenName }  ] setting with `NgModule`.

Try below code in app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [{
      provide: ServiceAA,
      useClass: NewServiceAA
  }]
})
export class Test {}
```

2. If you want to **override locally**, then while creating a component you can pass providers setting along with other component meta data then the overridden service instance will be local to the component or for all its children.

Try below code with component:

```
@Component({
   ...
   providers: [{
          provide: ServiceAA,
          useClass: NewServiceAA
   }]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not know why it does not work in nested modules with depth >= 2.
Is your answer applicable whenever the depth of the nested Module?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer

> @Component({    ...    providers: [{
> provide: ServiceAA,
> useClass: NewServiceAA    }] })

you need to confirm that the inner module is shared with (imported or inner exported) the module that provides service by other other instance.